# Combine 2 structures in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to join multiple order-lines into one order. But I can't get my system to do it, so I hope you can help with an XSLT that can do it in the file....

Old file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <TOTHEM>   <HEADER>
    <TYPE>INSDES</TYPE>
    <SENDER>me</SENDER>
    <RECEIVER>Them</RECEIVER>
    <DOCUMENT_REFERENCE>
      <ID>5655850111</ID>
      <TIMESTAMP>2022-11-30 11:42:52</TIMESTAMP>
    </DOCUMENT_REFERENCE>   </HEADER>   <ORDER ID="TO-20402">
    <EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO></EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO>
    <REFERENCE>TO-20402</REFERENCE>
    <ORDER_DATE>30-11-2022</ORDER_DATE>
    <DELIVERY_DATE>30-11-2022</DELIVERY_DATE>
    <PICK_COMMENT></PICK_COMMENT>
    <CARRIER></CARRIER>
    <SHIP>
      <SHIP_ID>me</SHIP_ID>
      <SHIP_NAME>me</SHIP_NAME>
      <SHIP_NAME2></SHIP_NAME2>
      <SHIP_ADDRESS>here</SHIP_ADDRESS>
      <SHIP_ADDRESS2></SHIP_ADDRESS2>
      <SHIP_POSTCODE>8600</SHIP_POSTCODE>
      <SHIP_CITY>Silkeborg</SHIP_CITY>
      <SHIP_COUNTRY_CODE>DK</SHIP_COUNTRY_CODE>
      <SHIP_ATT></SHIP_ATT>
      <SHIP_COMMENT></SHIP_COMMENT>
      <SHIP_MAIL></SHIP_MAIL>
      <SHIP_PHONE_NO></SHIP_PHONE_NO>
      <SHIP_SMS></SHIP_SMS>
    </SHIP>
    <RECEIVE>
      <RECEIVE_ID></RECEIVE_ID>
      <RECEIVE_NAME></RECEIVE_NAME>
      <RECEIVE_ADDRESS></RECEIVE_ADDRESS>
      <RECEIVE_ADDERSS2></RECEIVE_ADDERSS2>
      <RECEIVE_POSTCODE></RECEIVE_POSTCODE>
      <RECEIVE_CITY></RECEIVE_CITY>
      <RECEIVE_COUNTRY_CODE></RECEIVE_COUNTRY_CODE>
      <RECEIVE_CONTACT></RECEIVE_CONTACT>
    </RECEIVE>
    <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD1></ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
      ...
      <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD5></ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
    </ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
    <LINES>
      <LINE ID="4054009">
        <ARTICLE_NO>260250104</ARTICLE_NO>
        <ARTICLE_EAN>5707644776470</ARTICLE_EAN>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2>
        <ARTICLE_ID>102406528</ARTICLE_ID>
        <QUANTITY>150</QUANTITY>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>Pcs</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LOT_NO></LOT_NO>
        <EXPIRATION_DATE></EXPIRATION_DATE>
        <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
          ...
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
        </LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      </LINE>
    </LINES>   </ORDER>   <ORDER ID="TO-20403">
    <EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO></EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO>
    <REFERENCE>TO-20403</REFERENCE>
    <ORDER_DATE>30-11-2022</ORDER_DATE>
    <DELIVERY_DATE>30-11-2022</DELIVERY_DATE>
    <PICK_COMMENT></PICK_COMMENT>
    <CARRIER></CARRIER>
    <LINES>
      <LINE ID="4054010">
        <ARTICLE_NO>164800001</ARTICLE_NO>
        <ARTICLE_EAN>5707644835962</ARTICLE_EAN>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2>
        <ARTICLE_ID>102406639</ARTICLE_ID>
        <QUANTITY>500</QUANTITY>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>Pcs</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LOT_NO></LOT_NO>
        <EXPIRATION_DATE></EXPIRATION_DATE>
        <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
          ...
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
        </LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      </LINE>
    </LINES>
   </ORDER>
 </TOTHEM>
```

and I want it to end up like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> <TOTHEM>   <HEADER>
    <TYPE>INSDES</TYPE>
    <SENDER>me</SENDER>
    <RECEIVER>Them</RECEIVER>
    <DOCUMENT_REFERENCE>
      <ID>5655850111</ID>
      <TIMESTAMP>2022-11-30 11:42:52</TIMESTAMP>
    </DOCUMENT_REFERENCE>   </HEADER>   <ORDER ID="TO-20402">
    <EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO></EXTERNAL_DOCUMENT_NO>
    <REFERENCE>TO-20402</REFERENCE>
    <ORDER_DATE>30-11-2022</ORDER_DATE>
    <DELIVERY_DATE>30-11-2022</DELIVERY_DATE>
    <PICK_COMMENT></PICK_COMMENT>
    <CARRIER></CARRIER>
    <SHIP>
      <SHIP_ID>me</SHIP_ID>
      <SHIP_NAME>me</SHIP_NAME>
      <SHIP_NAME2></SHIP_NAME2>
      <SHIP_ADDRESS>here</SHIP_ADDRESS>
      <SHIP_ADDRESS2></SHIP_ADDRESS2>
      <SHIP_POSTCODE>8600</SHIP_POSTCODE>
      <SHIP_CITY>Silkeborg</SHIP_CITY>
      <SHIP_COUNTRY_CODE>DK</SHIP_COUNTRY_CODE>
      <SHIP_ATT></SHIP_ATT>
      <SHIP_COMMENT></SHIP_COMMENT>
      <SHIP_MAIL></SHIP_MAIL>
      <SHIP_PHONE_NO></SHIP_PHONE_NO>
      <SHIP_SMS></SHIP_SMS>
    </SHIP>
    <RECEIVE>
      <RECEIVE_ID></RECEIVE_ID>
      <RECEIVE_NAME></RECEIVE_NAME>
      <RECEIVE_ADDRESS></RECEIVE_ADDRESS>
      <RECEIVE_ADDERSS2></RECEIVE_ADDERSS2>
      <RECEIVE_POSTCODE></RECEIVE_POSTCODE>
      <RECEIVE_CITY></RECEIVE_CITY>
      <RECEIVE_COUNTRY_CODE></RECEIVE_COUNTRY_CODE>
      <RECEIVE_CONTACT></RECEIVE_CONTACT>
    </RECEIVE>
    <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD1></ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
      ...
      <ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD5></ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
    </ORDER_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
    <LINES>
      <LINE ID="4054009">
        <ARTICLE_NO>260250104</ARTICLE_NO>
        <ARTICLE_EAN>5707644776470</ARTICLE_EAN>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2>
        <ARTICLE_ID>102406528</ARTICLE_ID>
        <QUANTITY>150</QUANTITY>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>Pcs</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LOT_NO></LOT_NO>
        <EXPIRATION_DATE></EXPIRATION_DATE>
        <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
          ...
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
        </LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      </LINE>
      <LINE ID="4054010">
        <ARTICLE_NO>164800001</ARTICLE_NO>
        <ARTICLE_EAN>5707644835962</ARTICLE_EAN>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION>
        <ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2></ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION2>
        <ARTICLE_ID>102406639</ARTICLE_ID>
        <QUANTITY>500</QUANTITY>
        <UNIT_OF_MEASURE>Pcs</UNIT_OF_MEASURE>
        <LOT_NO></LOT_NO>
        <EXPIRATION_DATE></EXPIRATION_DATE>
        <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD1>
          ...
          <LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5></LINE_CUSTOM_FIELD5>
        </LINE_CUSTOM_FIELDS>
      </LINE>
    </LINES>
   </ORDER>
 </TOTHEM>
```

But I'm not experienced enough in XSLT to make it happen... anyone have good ideas?

It is asking me for more details, but I have no idea what to write here.....

Comment: Please reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem (see: [mcve]) and explain the logic you want to apply. Then ask about a **specific**  difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very difficult to follow (too much code to read). I get the impression that all you want to do is move all LINEs, from all ORDERS, into the first ORDER and remove all other ORDERs. It doesn't seem to make much sense, but if you like it can be done easily:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/TOTHEM">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="HEADER | ORDER[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LINES">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//LINE"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you!   sooo close...
only problem is that is eats some things:  (and yes it looks like it is also a problem in my example, but that is editing errors)
It removes the "newline"
after the Xml declaration,
after the <TOTHEM>
After the </HEADER>
After the <LINES>
After the </LINE>
after the </ORDER>

:-/

Comment: Nevermind. fixed it with another XSLT script.

Comment: Whitespace in XML is rarely significant. Perhaps you need to add  `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` and possibly also `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`. Depends on which processor you use.